# why is typescript returning this compile error even though the code is checking for undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I think that usually if code has a guard in place to check for an "undefined" value as shown below, then there should be no issue with code like line 249 below, since the undefined value was already guarded/validated.  However, I'm getting the following error below, despite the guard:

```
Argument of type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.  TS2345

    247 |           tabReport = getTabReportByType(tabId, view);
    248 |           if(tabReport != undefined){
  > 249 |               setTabReports(prevMap => new Map(prevMap.set(tabId, tabReport)));
        |                                                                   ^
    250 |           }
    251 |       }
    252 |   }
```

Any idea why the Typescript compiler is returning an error for this particular scenario?

Comment: How does the compiler know that `setTabReports()` runs the callback immediately?  The compiler doesn't know that `tabReport` won't be `undefined`  when the callback runs (and neither do I from that small snippet; maybe it gets reassigned in line 253), so it resets the narrowing.  I can flesh that out into an answer if you want.  I note that your question as asked is "why" and not "how can I refactor to prevent this", so if you care about the latter then you might want to edit that in.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41371 is a relevant issue

Comment: And https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37802#issuecomment-612309314 specifically saying that it would be too expensive for the compiler to check that `tabReport` is never assigned after the callback is defined, so it assumes it could be (unless `tabReport` is a `const`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `tabReport` in a callback function, typescript doesn't know whether that code will execute synchronously or asynchronously. If it happens asynchronously, and if `tabReport` is a `let` (or `var`), then the value might change by the time it runs. So as far as typescript can tell, the value might become `undefined` by the time the function runs.

The simplest fix for this is just to make `tabReport` a `const`:

```
const tabReport = getTabReportByType(tabId, view);
// rest is same as before
```

If the `tabReport` variable is serving some other purpose and you need to keep it a `let`, you could have an extra variable which is a const:

```
tabReport = getTabReportbyType(tabId, view);
const tabConst = tabReport;
if (tabConst !== undefined) {
  setTabReports(prevMap => new Map(prevMap.set(tabId, tabConst)));
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41371 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37802#issuecomment-612309314 are relevant; maybe you want to point to them in the answer (or maybe this comment will not be removed by mods)